# Response Redirect URL returns HTTP Error 400 - Bad Request

Tags: asp.net, http, iis, response.redirect, http-error

I'm a noob when it comes to ASP.NET. I know few basic commands such as Response.Redirect("URL") to redirect my application web page to a different location.

However i receive HTTP Error 400 - Bad Request, whenever i try to use the code shown below

```
Response.Redirect(Server.UrlEncode(this.Downloadlink));
```

where **this.Downloadlink** is a user defined property which returns something like this

```
 http://mdn.vatsag.net/fp;files/DOWNLOAD/VTSetup.exe
```

If i post this link in the browser, the .exe file pops up (means the link is good)

However this error comes when i use the ASP.NET code.

Any form of response on this issue/reason is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

See here: http://www.kirit.com/Response.Redirect%20and%20encoded%20URIs

In short: if you quickly want to fix the issue, remove the part of your code that is UrlEncoding the URL!

Comment: I tried the code on my end, at it works like a charm. Do you mean that the browser can not find the file? Or do you mean that the browser is redirected, but the file is not downloaded? Please be more specific about the error.